# Blurry/Fuzzy image on load with Vimeo embed iframe

Tags: javascript, jquery, vimeo

I have an embedded vimeo video iframe that is blurry upon the page fully loading. On desktop things are usually fine here, but mobile it gets blurry.

How can I prevent the blur on initial load on mobile (normally, it goes away if I click on it or it is fully loaded).

Is there a setting for this with vimeo embeds that I'm missing? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Leaving this to help next poor sucker.
In my case this was being cause by using jQuery show() and hide().
I have a single player that I dynamically pass the url and other attributes to.
So I would hide() it, change url, then show() it.
This eliminates the flicker of the video src changing.

It would work, but randomly lock up in that very blurry state, if you clicked on the video enough it would load.

Solved by using fadeTo().

videoUrl = vimeo link.

$('#playerContainer').fadeTo(0, 0); // speed, opacity

$('#yourPlayerIframe').attr('src', videoUrl);

$('#yourPlayerIframe').on("load", function() {

$('#playerContainer').fadeTo('fast', 1);

)};